# how to Use system properties to pass parameters to the runner/maven build

Tags: maven, selenium-webdriver, pom.xml, system-properties

I want to run my test in three different preset resolution: 768x1024, 360x740, 1920x1024 using the existing framework. And I have to use system properties to pass parameters to the runner/maven build. I've tried `systemPropertyVariable`. It worked fine with one resolution size but I don't know how to pass all the three preset resolutions.

```xml
private static void setupBrowser(final WebDriver webDriver) {

    String width=System.getProperty("width");
    String heigth=System.getProperty("heigth");
    
    final Dimension targetResolution = new Dimension(Integer.parseInt(width),Integer.parseInt(heigth));
```

here my `systemPropertyVariables`:

```
<configuration>
    <systemPropertyVariables>
        <width>768</width>
        <heigth>1024</heigth>
    </systemPropertyVariables>
    <suiteXmlFiles>
        <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
    </suiteXmlFiles>
</configuration>
```

Comment: `<systemPropertyVariables><width1>768</width1><height1>1024</height1><width2>...</width2><height2>...</height2><width3>...</width3><height3>...</height3>`?

Comment: @GeroldBroser  how can I read all the system variables in my setBrowser metthod?